# Export to excel error in PHP reports

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I export reports as excel using PHP & MySql. I can export and open the file from my localhost using my source code, but unable to do in the server. When I try to export it shows 
"
`Warning: tempnam() [function.tempnam]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/home:/tmp:/usr) in /home/xx/xx.inc.php on line 205.`" 
 I googled through, but I'm unable get the solution.

> $this->_tmpfilename=tempnam("/tmp", "excelreport");
>
> $fh=fopen($this->_tmpfilename, "w+b");

This is the code that used. What's wrong.

Comment: Check your server temp path and necessary folder permissions

Comment: What library are you using to create your Excel file? If it uses temporary files, then it should provide some method for you to say where those files are created

Comment: I use the php_writeexcel/ written by Johan

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting restricts your PHP activity within your home folder. Create a `tmp` folder within your home folder (i.e. `/home/xx/tmp/` ), chmod it `777` to solve this problem.

Note: the `/tmp` folder is used by the server itself.  In shared hosting environment, you are often restricted not to touch the server's system folders ( folders other than `/home` )

Comment: I tried & still the same warning message

Comment: what is the full path of your file ?

Comment: /home/xx/public_html/pms/excelreport

Comment: then your code should be `$this->_tmpfilename=tempnam("/home/xx/public_html/pms/", "excelreport");`